# SQL: Comparing Dates with only Month and Year columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a table `MonthlyShipments` that looks like:

```
partnumber | quantity | month | year |
part1      |       12 |     6 | 2011 |
part1      |       22 |     5 | 2011 |
part1      |       32 |     4 | 2011 |
part1      |       42 |     3 | 2011 |
part1      |       52 |     2 | 2011 |
```

I want to sum the quantities of the past 3 months, excluding the current month.  My where clause currently looks like:

```
where
  MonthlyShipments.Month <> MONTH(GETDATE()) AND 
  CAST(
    (CAST(MonthlyShipments.Month as nvarchar(2)) + 
    '-01-' + 
    CAST(MonthlyShipments.Year as nvarchar(4))) as DateTime)
  > DATEADD(m, -4, GETDATE())
```

It works, but its ugly and insulting.  Any advice on making it prettier?  Much appreciate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not much better...

```
DATEDIFF(
    month,
    DATEADD(Year, MonthlyShipments.Year-1900,
        DATEADD(Month, MonthlyShipments.Month-1, 0)
           ),
    GETDATE()
    ) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

however the nested DATEADD can be made a computed and indexed column

```
ALTER TABLE MonthlyShipments ADD
    ShipDate AS DATEADD(Year, MonthlyShipments.Year-1900,
            DATEADD(Month, MonthlyShipments.Month-1, 0)
               )
```

which gives

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, ShipDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Comment: even the first one is much better ... simply getting rid of string concatenation is 100x better :)

Comment: You could simplify this to a single DateAdd call: `DateAdd( Month, (MonthlyShipments.Year - 1900) * 12 + MonthlyShipments.Month - 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a date column?  If you need to do date calculations and you don't want things to get ugly this is probably going to be a requirement.  Even a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) would work...

Then you can just do something like this:

```
WHERE datecolumn < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your month+date to `date` and then compare it with current date:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(m,CONVERT(DATE, [month]+'/01/'+[year],101), GETDATE()) 
BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Or as it was said by others you can create a new computed column that holds `date` type

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `(year,month)` index, this will make use of it, I think:

```
FROM MonthlyShipments ms
WHERE ( ms.year = YEAR(GetDate()) 
        AND ms.month BETWEEN MONTH(GetDate())-3
                         AND MONTH(GetDate())-1
      )
   OR ( ms.year = YEAR(GetDate())-1
        AND ms.month BETWEEN 12 + MONTH(GetDate())-3
                         AND 12 + MONTH(GetDate())-1
      )
```

Not looking much prettier though.