# select columns between month and year

Tags: sql

I have table with columns:

```
id  month   year
1   10  2011
2   1   2012
3   4   2011
4   3   2012
```

I Want select ids where (month=10 and year=2011) and (month=1 and year=2012), it's possible?

Comment: (month=10 and year=2011) and (month=1 and year=2012)? This will give you an empty solution. Do you mean or?

Comment: I think you need (month = 10 AND year = 2011) OR (month = 1 AND year = 2012)

Comment: Are you saying you need all the IDs between *from* month 10, year 2011 *to* month 1, year 2012?

Comment: yes i need all the IDs between from month 10, year 2011 to month 1, year 2012

Comment: That is a clarification that is crucial to the correct understanding of your question, so **please edit your question** instead of commenting. Also, this question [has already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283703/sql-comparing-dates-with-only-month-and-year-columns "SQL: Comparing Dates with only Month and Year columns"), maybe just not for the SQL product you are using (which you haven't specified either, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic SQL SELECT:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE (month = 10 AND year = 2011) OR (month = 1 AND year = 2012);
```

Comment: Come on... This was realy easy. He should have solve this on his own.

Comment: I know. That's the reason why I want to jump out the window.

Comment: I wrong write, i want ids where month is > 10 year>2011 and month<1 and year<2012

Comment: I think you're confusing boolean AND with English AND. If you want two different sets of things, that's boolean OR.

Comment: Excuse me. But how can a month be > 2011 and < 2012 at the same time? There is no month 11.5. Same with month < 1. Month 0.5 or month -1?

Comment: @WojciechRadzioch: Please don't correct yourself in a comment, **edit the question** instead.

Answer (score 0):

To search for rows between any two dates, the simplest solution may be to combine the month and year into a single number and then use numeric comparison:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
WHERE year*100 + month BETWEEN 201110 AND 201201
```

A misfeature of this solution is that it can't take advantage of indexes, so it will be slow on very large tables.